# images inside wp-content/ uploads/ are not showing up in my media library and uploaded using FTP protocol

Tags: media-library

Hello would anybody be able to help my situation? at this point I'm wondering if it is a database issue because when i try the alternative to drag and drop an image into my media library i get this error-" could not insert post into the database". the hello? i have the permissions set up correct upload folder set to 744 as are the inner folders, the files set to 644.

also have set my wp-config.php file to direct to the correct table for my .sql database so not I'm stumped

thanks for the help

Comment: You can't add files to the media library via FTP, it's not a file browser. Attachments are posts in the database with associated files. If all you have is that error message then you have not completed debugging the issue. Disable all plugins and switch to a default theme, test, then re-enable them one by one until the problem returns. Also, a `.sql` file is not a database, it's a text file full of queries that recreates a databases contents and tables. Think of it as instructions on how to make pancakes, not actual pancakes

Comment: Permission on the folder should be 755. Change the folder permission (and it's parent folders) to 755, then try and upload via the Dashboard again.

Answer (score 0):

You’re most likely hitting the max upload or post memory.

Try to increase your memory limit in config

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

You may also need to change it in a php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this was my question. thanks for your replies- Tom J Nowell- yes i know  files will not show up simply from transferring them they existed in my uploads folder because the wordpress platform performed on my local computer and i thought if they would transfer once set to the server. the below screen shot shows the file structure in my c-panel file manager-
[image]

entreprenerds- thanks for your reply the permissions for my uploads folder was originally 755 but it wasn't working had the error "could not insert post into the database" so i found another source saying to change it to 744 keeping the files inside the 0644 (and still am getting the error- "could not insert post into the database")

sharulhafiz- i wish your reply could help i have the wp-config.php setup with this code- define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');
i don't think thats the issue since the images i have in the uploads folder worked just fine on my local machine before transferring to the server bluehost

there seems to be other variables why this won't work...or maybe something simple gah!